# mysql and or query together

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a search engine where a user can search by name,year,member,year(text field)

search will be with any one field
or
search will be with all the field
or
search will be with more than one field
-How it is possible by using only one query??
now my code is

```
$query="select * from fsb_profile where profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' and 
    profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' and profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."'  
    and profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."' or profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."'  
    or profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' or profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."'  
    or profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."'";
```

-but it is not working?

Comment: How many more of these questions are you going to ask?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql and or query run together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237397/mysql-and-or-query-run-together)

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (profile_name = '$profile_name' OR '$profile_name' = '')
  AND (profile_member = '$profile_member' OR '$profile_member' = '')
  AND ...
```

Alternatively you could build the query dynamically based on the fields you have.

Either way you should avoid putting data directly from user input into a query without first escaping it. Take a look at [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use bind parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$query="select * from fsb_profile where (profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' and profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' and profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."' and profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."') or (profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' or profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' or profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."' or profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."'");
```

This checks if all fields are set and if so, it will return that result, otherwise if any combination of the fields are set.